# Spring Flux doesn't retry even though instructed to do so

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

I'm using [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) and the gist of my application looks like this:

```
@StreamListener(MySink.SINK_NAME)
fun processEvents(events: Flux<Event>) {
        events.flatMap { event -> toEntities(event).toFlux() }
                .flatMap(myRepository::store)                   
                .doOnError { e -> log.error("Failed to store events", e) }
                .retry(3)
                .subscribe()
    }
```

where `MyRepository` is defined like this:

```
interface MyRepository {
    fun store(entity: Entity): Mono<UpdateResult>
}
```

I'm trying to simulate a failure so that I can make sure that retrying actually works and thus I've created a `@MockBean` of `MyRepository` and configuring the mock to first throw an exception:

```
given(myRepositoryMock.store(any())).willThrow(IllegalArgumentException("expected"))
                                    .willReturn(Mono.just(UpdateResult.acknowledged(...)))
```

But I cannot seem to trigger the retry behavior. I see that the exception is indeed caught and logged:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot comment on your code, since i dont have full info. Just wrote a simple piece of code. This code works `Flux<String> flux = Flux
        .range(1, 4)
        .map(item -> {
          if (item <= 3)
            return "item: " + item;
          else {
            System.out.println(">> Exception occured");
            throw new RuntimeException();
          }
        });

    flux.log().doOnError(System.out::println).retry(3).subscribe();`

Comment: Could it be that certain Flux streams are not retry:able?

Comment: I am not aware of any such thing. What retry does is to retry the method call, this is not related to the stream itself per se. Are you sure your test setup is right?

Comment: I think so, I've tried starting the app to simulate it manually (by publishing an event from the RabbitMQ console and changing the implementation of `MyRepository#store(..)` to throw exception) as well and I get the same result (i.e. no retry as far as I can tell). I've actually tried to debug the code in `reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry#onError(..)` and I can see that the method is indeed called but nothing noticable seems to happen when `resubscribe` is called.

Comment: Are there any events left? If an emitted event is considered as consumed (i.e. is no longer in the stream) and there is no other event in the stream then subscribing again works, but you get no values. Hence `myRepository::store` will never be called.

Comment: No there are no additional events left, so good point. I'd like to retry the operation with the _same_ event (i.e. the event that failed to be saved).